# I have this light in my scene that stops working and I have no Idea how to fix it. Can anyone solve this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting, light

I have 2 lights in my scene. They work fine until I look in the opposite direction: they just stop working. The even weirder thing is that one of the walls becomes darker when this light disappears and starts glitching with the other walls. It only happens in a specific part of the scene.

I tried playing with the light's settings and nothing worked. I even tried copying and pasting working lights but in that area it happens and I'm extremely frustrated.